# Getting a subquery to run N times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that scans a table with multiple status entries for each date, for each test, for each area in a system. The goal being to get the newest status for each date for each test in ONE given area. This would allow me to get a broad overview of a system to determine where the majority of tests are failing

Below is the basic table structure, but I've created [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e6356/3) for ease of use.

```
CREATE TABLE area (
    area_id integer NOT NULL,
    area_name character varying(100)
);

CREATE TABLE test (
    test_id integer NOT NULL,
    test_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    area_id integer NOT NULL,
    test_isvisible boolean DEFAULT true
);

CREATE TABLE status (
    status_date bigint NOT NULL,
    test_id integer NOT NULL,
    process_state_id integer NOT NULL,
    process_step_id integer NOT NULL,
    status_iteration integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    status_time bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE process_state (
    process_state_id integer NOT NULL,
    process_state_name character varying(100)
);

CREATE TABLE process_step (
    process_step_id integer NOT NULL,
    process_step_name character varying(100)
);
```

The query I currently have gets the furthest point of test processing for one single test for every date that is available. I would like to figure out a way to get that same type of information but instead pass the id of a given area, so that I can get that same data for each test in that area.

I.E. in the SQLFiddle, where I have information from dates July 2 - 10 for test1, I would also like the query to return the same set of information for test2, thus returning 18 rows instead of 9.

The main problem I'm having is that when I try to just join the area table and get all of the tests that way, I end up getting only 9 days of data like I did with one test, but just a mix-and-match of data from different tests.

Let me know if you need any more information, and I will post back here if I manage to figure it out before someone here.

**EDIT**
As was pointed out in the comments, this trial data does not have keys (primary or foreign) simply because it saved time and wasn't necessary for the problem at hand. It is important to note though, that these keys are 100% necessary in real world application, as the larger the dataset becomes, the more unruly and time consuming it would be to run queries against your tables.

*Lesson: Don't do drugs, do keys.*

Comment: 1) your tables are lacking primary keys. 2) your tables are lacking foreign keys 2a) and you probably want indexes for thes, too 3) do you really need to split the timestamps into separate *integer* date+time fields?

Comment: @wildplasser in my actual tables, I have both primary keys and foreign keys, but I'm not used to SQLFiddle, and it only gives you 8000 characters, and I preferred to have more actual data.
2a) the reason for splitting the time and date is because the test can be for code that was written on a certain day, while the test itself was run on a completely separate day. I wanted to retain the date of code creation, while capturing much more granular data about the time the test was run.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just saw them in the fiddle (which was down first time I looked). In most cases you also want extra indexes for the *outgoing* FKs, but you already have the composite 3-field PK for the status table.

Comment: You're quite right. I went ahead and added a little note at the bottom of the question letting people know about the lack of all the proper keys. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: Your status table has too many members in its primary key. As I see it, at least `{process_state_id, process_step_id}` should be removed from the PK, since they seem to be dependent on the PK (either `{test_id,status_datetime}` or `{test_id,status_iteration}`, both look like canditate keys to me) NOTE: if you **really** have a 3-field composite PK, you *could* have a 4NF/5NF normalisation problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple more hours, I found a different way to think about it, and finally got the data I was looking for.

I realized that my main problem with my previous attempts had been the use of GROUP BY, since I would have to group every selected column if I grouped any of them. So I first wrote a query that just got me the test_id/test_name along with each date that there was data for, since I knew I could group all of these no problem:

```
SELECT t.test_name AS test_name,
       to_char( to_timestamp(s.status_date)::TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS event_date,
       s.status_date
FROM status s
INNER JOIN test t ON t.test_id = s.test_id
INNER JOIN area a ON a.area_id = t.area_id
INNER JOIN process_step step ON s.process_step_id = step.process_step_id
INNER JOIN process_state state ON s.process_state_id = state.process_state_id
WHERE a.area_id = 12
GROUP BY t.test_id, s.status_date, t.test_name;
```

This didn't give me any information about where that test made it through (completed, failed, running). So then I wrote a separate query that simply got the test status when it was given a test_id and a status_date:

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN state.process_state_name = 'FAILURE' OR state.process_state_name = 'WAITING' OR state.process_state_name = 'VOLUME' THEN state.process_state_name
                WHEN step.process_step_name = 'COMPLETE' AND (state.process_state_name = 'SUCCESS' OR state.process_state_name = 'APPROVED') THEN 'Complete'
                ELSE 'Running'
        END AS process_state
FROM status s
INNER JOIN process_step step ON s.process_step_id = step.process_step_id
INNER JOIN process_state state ON s.process_state_id = state.process_state_id
WHERE s.test_id = 290
AND s.status_date = 1404273600
AND s.status_iteration = (SELECT MAX(s.status_iteration)
                          FROM status s
                          WHERE s.test_id = 290
                          AND s.status_date = 1404273600)
ORDER BY s.status_time DESC, s.process_step_id DESC, s.process_step_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

So this query worked for one single test and date, which I recognized would work perfectly for a subquery in my original query, since it would bypass the GROUP BY logic. So with that in mind, I proceeded to merge the two queries to get this one final query:

```
SELECT t.test_name AS test_name,
       to_char( to_timestamp(status.status_date)::TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS event_date,
       (
            SELECT 
                    CASE WHEN state.process_state_name = 'FAILURE' OR state.process_state_name = 'WAITING' OR state.process_state_name = 'VOLUME' THEN state.process_state_name
                            WHEN step.process_step_name = 'COMPLETE' AND (state.process_state_name = 'SUCCESS' OR state.process_state_name = 'APPROVED') THEN 'Complete'
                            ELSE 'Running'
                    END AS process_state
            FROM status s
            INNER JOIN process_step step ON s.process_step_id = step.process_step_id
            INNER JOIN process_state state ON s.process_state_id = state.process_state_id
            WHERE s.test_id = t.test_id
            AND s.status_date = status.status_date
            AND s.status_iteration = (SELECT MAX(s.status_iteration)
                                      FROM status s
                                      WHERE s.test_id = t.test_id
                                      AND s.status_date = status.status_date)
            ORDER BY s.status_time DESC, s.process_step_id DESC, s.process_step_id DESC
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS process_status
FROM status status
INNER JOIN test t ON t.test_id = status.test_id
INNER JOIN area a ON a.area_id = t.area_id
WHERE a.area_id = 12
GROUP BY t.test_id, status.status_date, t.test_name
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

And all of this can be seen in action in my [revised SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e6356/42).
Let me know if you have questions about what I did, hopefully this helps future developers.